# Adding conditions to a conditional statement

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, dynamic-arrays

I am messing around with dynamic arrays for a user defined amount of inputs for an and gate.

The issue I am running into is that I don't know how many inputs the user is going to test and I need to be able to have an if-else statement that tests each input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

class logic_gate {
public:
    int x = 0;

};

int main() {

int userInput = 0;

cout << "How many inputs do you want on your and gate?: ";
cin >> userInput;
cout << endl;

logic_gate *and_gate = new logic_gate[userInput];

cout << endl << "Please enter the values of each bit below . . ." << endl << 
endl;

int userTest1 = 0;


for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {

    cout << "#" << i + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> userTest1;
    and_gate[i].x = userTest1;

}

return 0;
}
```

Here is the code that I am currently trying to find a solution for.

Comment: "how I would test an unknown amount of values"... Why is the amount unknown, you have it in `userInput`, do you?

Comment: "an if-else statement that tests each input" Tests for what? Where is that `if` supposed to be? How is the input unknown? Do you have a chance to use `std::vector`?

Comment: Say the user chooses to have 20 inputs, I need to "and" all of those together to get the answer, (if all inputs are 1, then the output is 1, if any input is 0, then the output is 0). How do I test that with a variable amount of inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement an AND gate with `n` inputs you can simply do:

```
int output = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    if (!and_gate [i])
    {
        output = 0;
        break;
    }
}

// ...
```

Comment: I don't think I can implement this because I am passing an unknown amount of of values and I need to test each of them together. At least I think I do...

Comment: Think about it - the code I posted ANDs together all its inputs.

Comment: I am not really following, could you explain it further?

Answer (score 0):

Use Vector data structure, you don't need to tell its size while declaring, unlike array, and it can grow automatically.
To read input till it's arriving, put cin inside while loop condition. I used getline to read whole line and work with it, so that whenever user presses enter button at empty line, program will think that no more input is coming anymore, and will start calculating 'And' of inputs.

```
//don't forget to import vector
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>  
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class logic_gate {
public:
    int x = 0;
    logic_gate(){        //default constructor
    }
    logic_gate(int k){  //another constructor needed
        x = k;
    }
};

int main(){

    cout << endl << "Please enter the values of each bit below . . ." << endl;
    vector<logic_gate> and_gate;  //no need to tell size while declaration

    string b;
    while(getline(cin, b)){ //read whole line from standard input
        if (b == "\0")      //input is NULL
            break;
        and_gate.push_back(logic_gate(stoi(b))); //to convert string to integer
    }

    if (!and_gate.empty()){
        int output = and_gate[0].x;
        for (int i = 1; i < and_gate.size(); i++){
            output = output & and_gate[i].x;
        }       
        cout << "And of inputs is: " << output << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "No input was given!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask if some doubts linger

Comment: Here is the thing, I want the user to be able to declare what s/he wants the number of inputs to be. I understand that a vector can be used, but the same problem arises, I need to be able to test all of the inputs.

Comment: then I don't understand, what's wrong with **your** code? You are taking number of inputs and accordingly define the same size of array. While reading each input, you could do whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I wanted to do. Thanks to everyone who helped and especially Paul Sanders. Below is my final code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class logic_gate {
public:
    int x = 0;
};

int main() {

int userInput;
int output = 1;

cout << "How many inputs do you want on your and gate?: ";
cin >> userInput;
cout << endl;

logic_gate *and_gate = new logic_gate[userInput];

cout << endl << "Please enter the values of each bit below . . ." << endl << 
endl;

int userTest1;

for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {

    cout << "#" << i + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> userTest1;
    and_gate[i].x = userTest1;

}
if (userInput == 1) {
    output = userTest1;

    cout << "The test of " << userTest1 << " is " << output << endl << endl;

}
else if (userInput > 1) {

    for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {

    if (!and_gate[i].x)
    {
        output = 0;
        break;
    }

}

cout << "The test of ";

for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {

    cout << and_gate[i].x;

}

cout << " is " << output << endl << endl;

}

return 0;
}
```